# Add column field values in the same row?

Tags: sql, database, db2

Im working with SQL on db2.

**Shipping table:**

```
 +--------+------+
 | Weight | Cost |
 +--------+------+
 |      2 |    5 |
 |      5 |   10 | 
 |     10 |   15 | 
 |     30 |   45 |  
 |     50 |   80 |  
 +--------+------+
```

**Item table:**

```
  +---------+--------+
  | Item ID | Weight |  
  +---------+--------+
  |       1 |     34 |  
  |       2 |      4 | 
  |       3 |      9 |    
  |       4 |      5 |  
  |       5 |     16 |    
  +---------+--------+
```

I want to associate the appropriate shipping cost to the Item using the weight. So if the weight of the item would associate to the shipping weight equal to that or the next weight greater than that in the shipping weight table.

What I want my resulting table to be after INNER JOIN and everything is:

```
+---------+-------------+-----------------+---------------+
| Item ID | Item Weight | Shipping Weight | Shipping Cost | 
+---------+-------------+-----------------+---------------+
|       1 |          34 |              50 |            80 |   
|       2 |           4 |               5 |            10 |  
|       3 |           9 |              10 |            15 |  
|       4 |           5 |               5 |            10 |  
|       5 |          16 |              30 |            45 | 
+---------+-------------+-----------------+---------------+
```

I am unable to figure out how to associate the shipping weight to the item weight. Once I do that I can join the shipping cost.

What I tried was to use "WHERE >= Shipping Weight" but that gives me all the possibilities, and I just want the best one which is either equal than or next greatest. Im not good at explaining this but I hope you understand what I mean by looking at the resulting table I want.

Thanks!

Comment: Side note: My usual recommendation for positive numbers is "lower-bound inclusive, upper-bound exclusive" (that is, `lower <= actual weight < upper` - the opposite of what you show here).  The reason for this is dealing with the range of all numbers: consider what happens if any item weighs `30.00001` - it becomes much easier to reason about (you're currently storing the upper bound - why does the top one get carried over?)/query, _and_ to write the legal copy for.  In that scenario, you'd store the lower bound, meaning the top rate is just part of the normal last rate.

Comment: Also, regardless of which direction you store the bound, for ease of use I recommend creating a view or [materialized query table](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0061579.html) (which might help with speed, too, although the source table is likely small enough it shouldn't matter
).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can use a correlated subquery to get the weight and then a `join` to get the associated cost:

```
select i.*, s.*
from (select i.*,
             (select min(s.weight)
              from shipping s
              where s.weight >= i.weight
             ) as shipping_weight
      from items i
     ) i join
     shipping s
     on i.shipping_weight = s.weight;
```

Perhaps a funner method uses window functions:

```
select i.*, s.*
from items i join
     (select s.*, lag(weight) over (order by weight) as prev_weight
      from shipping s
     ) s
     on i.weight <= s.weight and
        (i.weight > prev_weight or prev_weight is null)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The "MIN(s.weight)" and "WHERE s.weight >= i.weight" part is what i needed. Cheers!